# Does creating new android wakelock with tag return same wakelock every time?

Tags: android, android-wake-lock, backgrounding

Title can be enigmatic. My question is simple i create wakelock:

```
pwrMgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "wakelock1")
```

Then i do this again in another place, with same tag, do i get same wakelock with acquiration references?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you do not. I wish that you did, as it would have simplified some scenarios. As [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#newWakeLock%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) indicates, it is solely for debugging purposes.

Comment: This is actually stupid i can't mark as accepted so fast, so i gonna do this later, thanks for answer.